blazor.webassembly.js:1 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=9.0.0.0,
I have upgrade my solution from .net8 to .net9. In .net8 everythings works fine.
But when upgraded to .net9 i get the following error:
[![blazor.webassembly.js:1 
 ManagedError: One or more errors occurred. (Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies.)][1]][1]

